# AutoMapper with auto-incremented values

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, automapper

```
public class OrderDTO
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderDetailDTO> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetailDTO
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say there are 4 `OrderDetailDTO`, I want to have the mapped `OrderDetail` instances with auto-incremented integer values. What I am doing now is post-process the mapped instance.

```
var mappedOrder = Mapper.Map<OrderDTO, Order>(orderDto);
var orderId = 1;
foreach (OrderDetail detail in mappedOrder.Details)
{
    detail.OrderId = orderId++;
}
```

How can I configure the mapping options, so that the mapped `ICollection<OrderDetail>` contains 4 `OrderDetail` instances with `OrderId` as 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: May I ask why? Do the `OrderId`s point to an existing `Order`s? If not, this is useless.

Comment: The code snippet is just an example. In my project I am not using these models.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could configure AutoMapper to do this with `AfterMap`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderDTO, Order>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
    {
        int orderId = 1;
        foreach (OrderDetail detail in dest.Details)
        {
            detail.OrderId = orderId++;
        }
    });
```

I don't think there's really a "cleaner" way to do it using AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following method which is much simpler and can be written in a base  class or an extension method. The example here uses Generics but can be easily transformed

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<T> ConvertCsvLines(IEnumerable<TV> lines)
{
    var lineNumber = 0;

    return lines.Select(x =>
    {
        var retVal = Mapper.Map<TV, T>(x);
        retVal.LineNumber = lineNumber++;
        return retVal;
    });
}
```