# c# auto mapper how to add auto-increment property to destination projection?

Tags: c#, automapper

We have source object "StockBase" and destination object as "StockDTO". While mapping "StockBase" to "StockDTO", we want to add a property that would give the index of collection i.e. auto increment by 1 in the "StockDTO" object.

For example "StockBase" has properties like Name, Owner, Color, Warranty.

While "StockDTO" has properties like Name, Owner + we want add Auto-increment-id that would give us rank of that Stock in collection starting from 1 and incremented by 1.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341945/automapper-with-auto-incremented-values) but is there any better way to do this when mapping list to list without duplicating things in aftermap?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent iterating collection more than once that I could think of, would be something like this:

```
public class A {  }

public class B { public int Index { get;set; } }

var colA = new List<A>();
var colB = colA.Select((a, ix) => 
{
   var b = Mapper.Map<B>(a);
   b.Index = ix + 1;
   return b;
});
```

So, code iterates only once through the collection, and uses `Mapper` and its mapping profiles, in addition auto incremented property is assigned during projection.

Note: Usually, you will not use static `Mapper` class, rather you will use injected `IMapper` instance.

Comment: but there might be performance hit here due to multiple calls to mapper.map, this is the only use case for which list mapping was developed

Comment: Latest versions of AutoMapper should cache the types, profiles and such things, so performance impact should not be such a big deal. However, you may test/measure it to be completely sure. Otherwise, you should go with the option in AfterMap where you will iterate through the whole collection one more time.